# LOD (Level Of Detail) where Year =

Tags: tableau-api

Trying to write a Calculation in Tableau that allows me to Fix Level of Detail on Category where year equal a designated date.

Imagine looks something like

`{FIXED [REPORT CATEGORY] : AVG(DOLLARS PAID)} WHERE YEAR = 2015`

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

1) You add the `YEAR` dimension to the LOD calculation and then add the `Year` to the filter card and set to '2015'. Your calculation would look like this:

Since you have no `YEAR`, you need to create a calculated field for it then reference it.

"YEAR" : `YEAR(APCD PAID ACCNTS DATE)`

`{ FIXED [REPORT CATEGORY], [YEAR]: AVG(DOLLARS PAID) }`

2) You can restrict the aggregation to only a specific year in the calculation, like so:

`{ FIXED [REPORT CATEGORY]: AVG(IF YEAR([APCD PAID ACCNTS DATE]) = 2015 THEN DOLLARS PAID END) }`

-- EDIT --

Updated above because you stated you are using a `DATE` not a number of the year.

Comment: Thank you for your response Nicarus! 

I  do not actually have [YEAR] as a dimension, rather full date under [PAID ACCNTS DATE] as a dimension.  I am getting error can't compare datetime and string values.  What is best method to solve this error and restrict data to year 2015?

Comment: {FIXED [PH_REPORT_CAT_DESC] : AVG(CASE [APCD PAID ACCNTS DATE] WHEN [APCD PAID ACCNTS DATE] = "2015" THEN [APCD_PAID_AMT] END)}

Comment: See my updated. Don't compare a string "2015" to a DATE - that won't work.